# How to convert image to video with DRM (FairPlay)

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, drm, fairplay

I want to hide some private content on screenshots. Since Apple provide us only `userDidTakeScreenshotNotification`, the only way to achieve this is to convert image to video with DRM. According to these [thread](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1970/_index.html):

> If your application uses FairPlay Streaming (FPS) your video content
>   will automatically not be captured by the iOS 11 screen recording
>   feature or QuickTime Player on macOS. The portion of your application
>   that is playing the content will be blacked out.

I found commercial implementation of these idea in ScreenShieldKit, but it costs money.

The main question:
*How it's possible to convert image or label to FairPlay Streaming (FPS) video in offline mode?*

Comment: Look for something called “common encryption”. You will also need a FairPlay server and certificate from Apple.

Comment: Ye, but these guys somehow achieved this without any servers, or internet connection at all. They protect content even in offline mode: screenshieldkit. Do you have any ideas how they do this?

Comment: My main goal is to hide content on screenshots.

Comment: @TanyaMarchuk did you ever figure this out?  I have a similar requirement.

Comment: I have a feeling that ScreenShieldKit is using a local KSM (FairPlay server) hosted inside the application. I don't think that is what Apple intended...

Btw: From what I remember, as long as you use SAMPLE-AES method for HLS you will also get screenshot blocking. (Not guaranteed... But seems to be the actual behavior).

Comment: @TanyaMarchuk Have u find the solution For this?

Comment: @TanyaMarchuk have you find any solution?

Comment: @TanyaMarchuk have you found any solution to this?